# How to loop through computer vision output array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, computer-vision

A computer vision model output blob is identified [like this](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/tree/master/models/intel/person-detection-0202#outputs):
`[image_id, label, conf, x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max], where:`

```
image_id - ID of the image in the batch
label - predicted class ID (0 - person)
conf - confidence for the predicted class
(x_min, y_min) - coordinates of the top left bounding box corner
(x_max, y_max) - coordinates of the bottom right bounding box corner
```

Just manually printing the array of in the code I am working with a `print(result_blob.tolist())`

The output looks like this:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.6192154288291931, 0.36988523602485657, 0.39582735300064087, 0.7380738258361816, 0.9911962151527405]
```

If I wanted to draw a bounding box with open CV around a person in the video feed with a confidence greater than .5 how do I loop through these elements in an numpy array to do so?

This repository also contains some code and a function to do this but I dont understand how it works or if there is a better way to write it? Can someone help me understand what `detections = result.reshape(-1, 7)` does and the Python `enumerate` below it? the cv2 drawing rectangles I get but the function is confusing on why the convert floats to ints, etc...

```
def postprocess(result, image, fps=None):
    """
    Define the postprocess function for output data
    
    :param: result: the inference results
            image: the orignal input frame
            fps: average throughput calculated for each frame
    :returns:
            image: the image with bounding box and fps message
    """
    detections = result.reshape(-1, 7)
    for i, detection in enumerate(detections):
        _, image_id, confidence, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = detection
        if confidence > 0.5:
            xmin = int(max((xmin * image.shape[1]), 10))
            ymin = int(max((ymin * image.shape[0]), 10))
            xmax = int(min((xmax * image.shape[1]), image.shape[1] - 10))
            ymax = int(min((ymax * image.shape[0]), image.shape[0] - 10))
            cv2.rectangle(image, (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.putText(image, str(round(fps, 2)) + " fps", (5, 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 255, 0), 3) 
    return image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function expects `result` to be a numpy array with a certain shape.
If there are *n* person detections the rest of the code expects an array with shape `(n, 7)`,
so an array with rows of length 7.
This is because there are 7 pieces of information per detection.
Thanks to the `reshape` the function is lenient wrt the passed shape,
like `(n, 7)` and `(n * 7)` and `(1, n, 7)` could work.

Making sure the shape is `(n, 7)` allows an easy loop over the detections.
Because in general a loop over the rows of a 2d numpy array can be written as:

```
for row in array:
    ...
```

Using `enumerate` on top of this just gives the index of the row.
However, this index isn't used in this case so the `enumerate` is useless here.
Probably this loop was copied from another postprocessing function and it was left in by accident.

The unpacking of the detection has `image_id` as the second element, so maybe another small error.
Since `image_id` is also not used it may be nicer to write:

```
confidence, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = detection[2:]
```

The 4 lines that convert `xmin` etc do two things:

1. Convert from relative coordinates to pixel coordinates (which have to be integers)
2. Make sure the rectangle isn't drawn within 10 pixels of the edge of the image

Comment: Any chance you could reiterate the last 2 bullets....relative coordinates Vs pixel coordinates? (`float` vs `int`?I guess makes sense too that the rectangle isnt drawn within 10 pixels of the edge else it would be off the image all together.